# REST WebServices - Is it a good or general practice to accept a JSON but return an XML or vice-versa?

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services, rest

I'm finding it a little bit tough to ask my question correctly to Google.

I'm building a REST Web Service, which can accept and return both XML and JSON media types. My client can decide what to send to my service (in case of a POST) by using the `Content-Type` header, and what it would like to recieve as a response by using the `Accept` header.

However, my question is, can I create a web service, such that it can accept only JSON (i.e., the client *has to* set `Content-type=application/json`), but the Service can return an XML only (the client *has to* set `Accept=application/xml`)?

While this can be technically possible, I would like to know if this is a good practice, and are there any general implementations of REST Webservices where a client can specify a particular `Content-Type` but a different `Accept` header.

Imagine I have implemented a Service like the one below:

```
@POST
@Path("/users")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public User createUser(User user) {
     /* Do something */
     return user;
}
```

In the above case, a client can send the Post data as JSON, but expect to receive the response as XML, and vice versa.

Is this really a good practice? Should or should a REST Service not emphasize on returning content with the same Media Type as it accepts? Like, produce `application/xml` when it consumes `application/xml` and produce `application/json` when it consumes `application/json` and so on?

Comment: it all depends on your requirement as you correctly mentioned that its technically possible, now depending on your requirement you can implement it, although de-facto standard for data-transfer now a days are JSON.

Comment: I don't think one can advise on this without knowing far more about the requirements on your project and the business drivers that determine its success. It's a decision at the requirements level, not at the engineering level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically possible, this is not good practice at all, especially if the client explicitely stated via its `Accept` header it only accepts `application/json`.

Instead of one method accepting both XML and JSON, you could make two methods on the same path, each one dedicated to one particular content-type:

```
@POST
@Path("/users")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public User createUserJson(User user) {
     /* Do something */
     return user;
}

@POST
@Path("/users")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public User createUserXml(User user) {
     /* Do something */
     return user;
}
```

See also the [Accept header spec in RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.1)

Comment: While using an object framework (axis2, cxf, ...) it framework does the serialization (XML, JSON) "itself" so I see no issue returning what the client asks (Accept header). Technically - the accept header is only "expected type", and the server may return what it returns (specified in the Content-Type header). So by definition it is still valid service, but IMHO the best practice is to return what client asks for if able, it makes the service more consumable